# Best Way to Validate E-mail (before sending link to complete registration)

Tags: registration, email, email-verification

I have a web application used by users with “little experience”.

The only field that exists on the home page is email.
If the user is already registered I request the password, otherwise I send an email to him to finish the registration.

My problem is that users occasionally type the wrong email and are waiting to receive the email to complete the registration.

I started a job to create a “Did you mean” tool, so if he type “anyone@gmail.cmo” I suggest “anyone@gmail.com” ...

I wanted your opinion on two topics:

1 - Should I open another field for him to re-type the email before sending the link to finalize the registration.

2 - Should I use a host validation API like https://trumail.io/ (afraid to block an email OK).

Or if someone has a similar experience and wants to share the solution that **brought greater conversion** would help me a lot

Comment: By 'occasionally' type the wrong email, how frequent is that? Sometimes the cost of implementing complicated technical processes or added visual noise to the page (such as extra fields) outweighs the benefits. You don't want to add stuff to the page that annoys *everyone* if you're just trying to capture that 1/1000 that got away.

Comment: Yesterday I had 85 new users (who completed the registration) and 15 emails that returned to me (they were not delivered because they were wrong).

I agree with you ... the big question is how to do this without burdening the "good" users who type the email correctly and help those more distracted as well.

Comment: It is tricky though to do email verification. Youwant to do better than most webapplication which refuse "User+sitename@domain.tld". (PLus sigh is valid and resolves to user@domain.tld with a tag). Or potentially "A@penootje"@domain.tld (I think that is valid).

Comment: For me, if you stick with the one email field on home page that leads to password capture, it makes sense to also go to verify email if it isn't recognised (then check again for registered ones, in case registered user did typo). This is consistent, at least. Might want to consider security implications of allowing someone to discover valid emails, via war dialling. May not be an issue for you, but should always consider these things.

Comment: 1 is discussed here --> https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/43015/what-is-behind-entering-email-twice-for-registration . Consensus seems to be unless it's critical let them realise their mistake by not receiving the confirmation email and following the approach in the answer K K gives below

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try following approaches instead:

1. Show a message to the user after sending a verification link or logging in. The message informs them about their input. For example:
   [image]
2. Show a message before sending them an email:
   [image]
3. Inform the user about the issue and let them take the action instead of you taking an action:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I now prefer to send a randomly generated code only to the email address and then prompt the user for the code immediately.  It means they can stay on the same browser tab in the signup flow and also it is not putting a link in an email which can be spoofed in phishing attacks.