# Has there been research into user behaviour on clipboard hijacking in browsers?

Tags: website-design, web, browser, copy-paste

There is a number of questions on the likes of super user asking to disable clipboard hijacking such as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/713797/how-can-i-stop-clipboard-hijacking-globally).

Personally I hate when sites do this and have a feeling it's partly because

- The behaviour of a system wide function, the clipboard, has been changed without been notified
- I explicitly selected the text and my wishes have been overruled without my authorisation

Has there been any research into either

1. Users behaviour when the clipboard has been modified
2. Users overall perception of clipboard hijacking

Answer (score -2):

I have no formal research into your issue directly but have recently implemented something similar to a eCommerce web application.

It is a requirement of the order confirmation page that the user enters their email address twice to increase accuracy. To allow the user to copy and paste their email address defeats the purpose of asking for it twice in the first place (as they could copy and paste it incorrectly twice), as such we incorporated a jquery to prevent the use of Ctrl-V and Paste in this second field. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-copy-paste-into-html-form-using-javascript).

The system is yet to launch fully, but the general feedback from UAT and Usability testing is that this is really annoying, **but** it forces the user to actively think about a field that is generally input through muscle memory, and is important to the business and eventual UX.

As I said this is not a direct answer to your question but this is a more common example of the scenario so you may find more behavioural feedback on it.

[Should I let a user copy/paste into a confirm e-mail field for a registration form?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1488/should-i-let-a-user-copy-paste-into-a-confirm-e-mail-field-for-a-registration-fo)

Comment: Please don't do this, there are many ways of dealing with an incorrect email address when you also get phone number and address plus card details / paypal etc. It's not good ux it's usually only done to ensure marketing info. You'll not see many big econmerce sites doing this, many just ask for email once. Rest assured that your customers will be in touch if an order is wrong and also that they'll be back if your product and services are good